# Comparar a la vez respuesta en mayúscula y en minúscula a una pregunta utilizando "equals"

Tags: java, string, comparaciones

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en java y tengo que comparar la respuesta ingresada:

> ¿desea continuar? s/n:

Debe contemplar tanto s como S

Necesito ejecutarlo con una sola respuesta

Comment: gracias,lo pude resolver añadiendo toLowerCase() !

Comment: Ya que lo mio fue un comentario, te sugiero que aceptes la respuesta de Joacer. Un saludo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes resolver esto utilizando la comprobación [equalsIgnoreCase()](http://www.w3api.com/wiki/Java:String.equalsIgnoreCase()), que compara la cadena de texto contra un objeto ignorando mayúsculas y minúsculas. Devolverá true si las cadenas comparadas son equivalentes (ignorando mayúsculas y minúsculas). En caso contrario devolverá false.

**Ejemplo:**

```
if("s".equalsIgnoreCase(respuesta)){
     //gestionas si es "si"
}else{
     //gestionas si es "no"
}
```

Otra alternativa sería utilizar la función [toLowerCase()](http://www.w3api.com/wiki/Java:String.toLowerCase()) como indica el compañero @lois6b, que convierte todos los caracteres de la cadena a minúsculas.

**Ejemplo:**

```
if("s".equals(respuesta.toLowerCase())){
     //gestionas si es "si"
}else{
     //gestionas si es "no"
}
```

Comment: Mucho mejor que utilizar `String#toLowerCase()` +1

Comment: ¿Que ocurre si se pone tilde? ('sí')

Comment: @HamzaAkiour si se pone "si" ó "sí" no funcionará, ya que se esta comparando únicamente con la letra "s" (s ó S), que es lo que el OP ha dicho que puede introducir el usuario. De todas formas esa función no tiene en cuenta las mayúsculas y minúsculas, pero los acentos si que los tiene en cuenta.

Comment: Cuando llego a mi casa lo pruebo,gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Por añadir a la respuesta de @Joacer, para el caso de que se necesite comparar ignorando las tildes, se puede hacer de la siguiente manera usando la clase Collator.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("es", "ES");
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(locale);
collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
if (collator.compare("Escocia", "Escocía") == 0) {
   System.out.println("Los considero iguales pese a no serlo");
} else {
   System.out.println("Son distintos");
}
```

Lo que se hace es crear un Collator del locale español (es_ES). A este collator se le configura con fuerza primaria, esto es, que considere que letras con tildes sean iguales a las letras sin tilde. (Hay varias opciones de configuración: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html)

Por último se compara con el método compare de esta clase, este método devuelve 0 si los considera iguales. En este caso, aunque todos sabemos que no es lo mismo estar en Escocia, que estar escocía, el método devuelve 0 porque los considera iguales.